# Huawei E586 MiFi modem- Is it possible to set up client to client links on this device?

Tags: wireless-networking, mifi

I am using E586 as a home hub. I can connect my laptop, desktop and digital tv unit OK and all can access WAN fine. I would like to access my digital tv unit from my laptop. I can see the dhcp allocated ip address for the digital tv unit but when i ping from my pc i only rx error message "destination host is unreachable". Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like the E583C then you need to make sure that "AP Isolation" is set to "Off" in the configuration.

Comment: Well done Ignacio, problem solved! Many thanks Ian